# python lxml etree applet information from yahoo

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

Yahoo finance updated their website. I had an lxml/etree script that used to extract the analyst recommendations. Now, however, the analyst recommendations are there, but only as a graphic. You can see an example on [this page](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CSX/analysts?p=CSX). The graph called Recommendation Trends on the right hand column shows the number of analyst reports showing strong buy, buy, hold, underperform, and sell.

My guess is that yahoo will make a few adjustments to the page over the coming little while, but it got me wondering whether such data was extractable in any reasonable way?

1. I mean, is there a way to get the graphic to work with that?
2. Even if one were successful, would there be a reasonable way to extract the data from the graphic?

I used to get the source like this:

```
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+code+'/analyst?p='+code
tree = etree.HTML(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
```

and then find the data in the html tree. But obviously that's impossible now.

Comment: From memory, they started using react so a lot of content is now dynamically created, how are you getting the source?

Comment: I put the code in the question. It definitely looks like the content is created dynamically. I guess I'm wondering if such content can be pulled anyway.

Comment: yes, I just had a look,  it is completely dynamically created including the colouring etc.. You can quite easily get the values using selenium though

Comment: I'll have to look up selenium. Never heard of it. Thanks for the pointer. Is it a Python thing?

Comment: It behaves like a browser i.e it can run Javascript, you can use it with Phantomjs for headless browsing. I did a bit of work with it and got all the x,y axis ticks, values etc.. quite easily, you can actually recreate the whole graph including the colour codes by extracting the values from the tags. It is too late to finish it now but if I get some free time tomorrow I will add the full implementation

Comment: I would really appreciate that. It sounds amazing.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, would you be able to just outline how this could be done? I don't want you to have to do the work, but wondered if you could just give me the bullet points or google search terms that might get me what I need?

Comment: they do not have any API to get this information's as a JSON data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments say they have moved to ReactJS, so `lxml` is no longer to the point because there's no data in the HTML page. Now you need to look around and find the endpoint where they are pulling the data from. In case of *Recommendation Trends* it's there.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import json
from pprint import pprint
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode


def parse():
    host   = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com'
    path   = '/v10/finance/quoteSummary/CSX'
    params = {
        'formatted' : 'true',
        'lang'      : 'en-US',
        'region'    : 'US',
        'modules'   : 'recommendationTrend'
    }

    response = urlopen('{}{}?{}'.format(host, path, urlencode(params)))
    data = json.loads(response.read().decode())

    pprint(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse()
```

The output looks like this.

```
{
  'quoteSummary': {
    'error': None,
    'result': [{
      'recommendationTrend': {
        'maxAge': 86400,
        'trend': [{
            'buy': 0,
            'hold': 0,
            'period': '0w',
            'sell': 0,
            'strongBuy': 0,
            'strongSell': 0
          },
          {
            'buy': 0,
            'hold': 0,
            'period': '-1w',
            'sell': 0,
            'strongBuy': 0,
            'strongSell': 0
          },
          {
            'buy': 5,
            'hold': 12,
            'period': '0m',
            'sell': 2,
            'strongBuy': 6,
            'strongSell': 1
          },
          {
            'buy': 5,
            'hold': 12,
            'period': '-1m',
            'sell': 2,
            'strongBuy': 7,
            'strongSell': 1
          },
          {
            'buy': 6,
            'hold': 11,
            'period': '-2m',
            'sell': 2,
            'strongBuy': 8,
            'strongSell': 1
          },
          {
            'buy': 6,
            'hold': 11,
            'period': '-3m',
            'sell': 2,
            'strongBuy': 8,
            'strongSell': 1
          }]
        }
    }]
  }
}
```

## How to look for data

What I did was roughly:

1. Find some unique token in the target widget (say chart value or *Trend* string)
2. Open source of the page (use some formatter for HTML and JS, e.g. [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/))
3. Look for the token there (in the the page three is section that starts with `/* -- Data -- */`)
4. Search for ".js" to get script tags (or programmatic inclusions, e.g. require.js) and look for token there
5. Open network tab in Firebug or Chromium Developer Tools and inspect XHR requests
6. Then use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (or curl if you prefer terminal) to strip extra parameters and see how the endpoint reacts

Comment: Green technology in comparison to having a full featured browser and remote control to it ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid someone posts a direct approach. Definitely deserves the bounty!

Comment: This really works well. I was wondering how you were able to determine the right stuff to put into the params? I only vaguely understand what it is doing, so thought it would be useful to understand how I would adapt the code for other information (say target price or whatever).

Comment: @DrXorile I've added a section. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks again. This is brilliant.

Comment: This does not seem to be working anymore. I get a "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized"

Answer (score 4):

The page is *quite dynamic* and involves a lot of javascript executed in a browser. To follow the @Padraic's advice about switching to [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), here is a complete sample working code that produces a month-to-trend dictionary at the end. The values of each bar are calculated as proportions of bar heights:

```
from pprint import pprint

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CSX/analysts?p=CSX")

# wait for the chart to be visible
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
trends = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section[data-reactid$=trends]")))
chart = trends.find_element_by_css_selector("svg.ratings-chart")

# get labels
month_names = [month.text for month in chart.find_elements_by_css_selector("g.x-axis g.tick")]
trend_names = [trend.text for trend in trends.find_elements_by_css_selector("table tr > td:nth-of-type(2)")]

# construct month-to-trend dictionary
data = {}
months = chart.find_elements_by_css_selector("g[transform]:not([class])")
for month_name, month_data in zip(month_names, months):
    total = month_data.find_element_by_css_selector("text.total").text
    data[month_name] = {'total': total}

    bars = month_data.find_elements_by_css_selector("g.bar rect")

    # let's calculate the values of bars as proportions of a bar height
    heights = {trend_name: int(bar.get_attribute("height")) for trend_name, bar in zip(trend_names[::-1], bars)}
    total_height = sum(heights.values())
    for trend_name, bar in zip(trend_names, bars):
        data[month_name][trend_name] = heights[trend_name] * 100 / total_height

driver.close()

pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
{u'Aug': {u'Buy': 19,
          u'Hold': 45,
          u'Sell': 3,
          u'Strong Buy': 22,
          u'Underperform': 8,
          'total': u'26'},
 u'Jul': {u'Buy': 18,
          u'Hold': 44,
          u'Sell': 3,
          u'Strong Buy': 25,
          u'Underperform': 7,
          'total': u'27'},
 u'Jun': {u'Buy': 21,
          u'Hold': 38,
          u'Sell': 3,
          u'Strong Buy': 28,
          u'Underperform': 7,
          'total': u'28'},
 u'May': {u'Buy': 21,
          u'Hold': 38,
          u'Sell': 3,
          u'Strong Buy': 28,
          u'Underperform': 7,
          'total': u'28'}}
```

The `total` values are labels that you see on top of each bar.

Hope this would at least be a good start for you. Let me know if you want me to elaborate on any part of the code or require any additional information.