# python web-scraping yahoo finance

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

Since Yahoo finance updated their website. some tables seem to be created dynamically and not actually stored in the HTML (I used to get this information using BeautifulSoup, urllib but this won't work anymore).  I am after the Analyst tables for example [ADP](http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ADP/analysts?p=ADP) specifically the Earnings Estimates for Year Ago EPS (Current Year Column). You cannot get this information from the API.

I found this link which works well for the Analyst Recommendations Trends. does anyone know how to do something similar for the main table on this page? (LINK: 
[python lxml etree applet information from yahoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007227/python-lxml-etree-applet-information-from-yahoo)  )

I tried to follow the steps taken but frankly its beyond me. 
returning the whole table is all I need I can pick out bits from there. cheers

Comment: Isn't the data you need available via [API](http://meumobi.github.io/stocks%20apis/2016/03/13/get-realtime-stock-quotes-yahoo-finance-api.html)?

Comment: You can use this [endpoint](https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/ADP?formatted=true&crumb=.U2WzFPwWfy&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=upgradeDowngradeHistory%2CrecommendationTrend%2CfinancialData%2CearningsHistory%2CearningsTrend%2CindustryTrend%2CindexTrend%2CsectorTrend&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com). It returns all desired data in json format. For parsing that data you can use [Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).

Comment: Hi vold.  how did you get that endpoint url?  I need to be able to generate a url such as this dynamically for any ticker.  I can see the data is there all I would need to do is parse it as you say.

Comment: actually if I just replace the ticker on that endpoint with another ticker that works.  thanks   and fedterzi as I said in the original post its not in the api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get that data, you need to open Chrome DevTools and select Network tab with XHR filter. If you click on ADP request you can see link in RequestUrl.

[image]

You can use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) library for making a request and parsing json response from the site.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/ADP?formatted=true&crumb=ILlIC9tOoXt&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=upgradeDowngradeHistory%2CrecommendationTrend%2CfinancialData%2CearningsHistory%2CearningsTrend%2CindustryTrend%2CindexTrend%2CsectorTrend&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com'
r = requests.get(url).json()
pprint(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

further to volds answer above and using the answer in the link I posted above. (credit to saaj).  This gives just the dataset I need and is neater when calling the module.  I am not sure what the parameter crumb is but, it seems to work ok without it.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def parse():
    host   = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com'
    #host   = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com'  # try if above doesn't work
    path   = '/v10/finance/quoteSummary/%s' % 'ADP'
    params = {
        'formatted' : 'true',
        #'crumb'     : 'ILlIC9tOoXt',
        'lang'      : 'en-US',
        'region'    : 'US',
        'modules'   : 'earningsTrend',
        'domain'    : 'finance.yahoo.com'
    }

    response = urlopen('{}{}?{}'.format(host, path, urlencode(params)))
    data = json.loads(response.read().decode())

    pprint(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse()
```

Other modules (just add a comma between them):
assetProfile
financialData
defaultKeyStatistics
calendarEvents
incomeStatementHistory
cashflowStatementHistory
balanceSheetHistory
recommendationTrend
upgradeDowngradeHistory
earningsHistory
earningsTrend
industryTrend

Answer (score 0):

In GitHub, [c0redumb](https://github.com/c0redumb/yahoo_quote_download/tree/master/yahoo_quote_download) has proposed a whole solution. You can download the [yqd.py](https://github.com/c0redumb/yahoo_quote_download/blob/master/yahoo_quote_download/yqd.py). After import it, you can get Yahoo finance data by one line of code, as blew.

```
import yqd
yf_data = yqd.load_yahoo_quote('GOOG', '20170722', '20170725')
```

The result 'yf_data' is:

```
['Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume',
 '2017-07-24,972.219971,986.200012,970.770020,980.340027,980.340027,3248300',
 '2017-07-25,953.809998,959.700012,945.400024,950.700012,950.700012,4661000',
 '']
```